# mssql DISTINCT and sorting

Tags: sql-server

```
mnum | mname | tnum | tname | note | time
7788   test1   1133   test2    hi    2014/10/01
7788   test1   1133   test2    hi2   2014/10/08
7788   test1   1133   test2    hi3   2014/10/03
1133   test2   7788   test1    tt2   2014/10/10
1133   test2   7788   test1    tt3   2014/10/05
9990   test3   9992   test4    hh1   2014/10/10
9990   test3   9992   test4    hh1   2014/10/01
```

if i will get 7788 on mnum or tnum, and distinct and order by time desc

```
select * from xxxx where mnum=7788
```

can get result:

```
7788 2014/10/10 (only one result)
1133 2014/10/08 (only one result)
```

Comment: please reword your question as it is quite hard to understand in its current form

Comment: Forget DISTINCT keyword - this can be usable in quick problem solving or in some COUNT() expressions, but in general queries it makes usually no sense. You can use grouping, aggregate functions, windowing functions, CTEs - but first you have clearely describe what you need (this usually hints to solution also). BTW, from your data, your result is not obtainable at all, because your dates are inconsistent :)

Comment: yes....i distinct mnum, tnum first, then num add to array, then for array to select key on num order by times desc add to array2, then select * from table where key in array2...it ok..but......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. take distinct mnum and tnum
2. num add to array
3. take select key from table where num order by times desc and add result to array2
4. select * from table where key in (array2)